# Instagram login OAuth issue in Laravel5.4

Tags: php, laravel, instagram, laravel-5.4

I try to login by Instagram , and I refer to [LaravelでInstagramに投稿された写真を全取得してみた](https://qiita.com/daiki_44/items/6d01029cd3a7e7111c9a)

When I try to login,it have some problem,it redirect go to home page,can not show any user information,but I want to show user information on the page. 
[image: picture]
How can I fix this problem ? thanks.

---

Step by Step:

1.Install cosenary/instagram

```
composer require cosenary/instagram
```

2.Setting Instagram Developer
[image: IG DEP]

3.Setting 'client_id' ,'client_secret' and 'callback_url' on ../config/instagram.php:

```
<?php

return [

    'client_id'     => '0264df4679584XXXXXX313e5bd90',
    'client_secret' => '6eXXXXXXf369298c5433084ee21',
    'callback_url'  => 'http://localhost/',
    'scopes'        => 'basic public_content'

];
```

4.InstagramController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram;

class InstagramController extends Controller
{
    private $instagram;

    function __construct() {

        $this->instagram = new Instagram(array(
            'apiKey' => config('instagram.client_id'),
            'apiSecret' => config('instagram.client_secret'),
            'apiCallback' => config('instagram.callback_url')
        ));
    }


    public function instagramLogin() {
        return redirect($this->instagram->getLoginUrl(array(
            'basic'
        )));
    }


    public function instagramCallback(Request $request) {
        $code = $request->code;

        $data = $this->instagram->getOAuthToken($code);
        $this->instagram->setAccessToken($data);

        $user_data = $this->instagram->getUser();
        dd($user_data);
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($user_data);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

5.Setting ../routes/web.php

```
Route::get('login/instagram/', 'InstagramController@instagramLogin');

# Instagram callback
    Route::get('login/instagram/callback/', 'InstagramController@instagramCallback');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being redirected to `http://localhost` which is just the Laravel main page.

You need to redirect to the Instagram callback route instead.

In `config/instagram.php` update your setting:

```
'callback_url' => 'http://localhost/login/instagram/callback',
```

Or if you have your .env set up:

```
'callback_url' => env('APP_URL') . '/login/instagram/callback',
```